# PHP what does :: mean?

Tags: php, magento

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this symbol mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php)

I've come accross this notation in PHP magento 'Mage::run()'.

What does :: mean?  Can't seem to find a simple explanation anywhere.

Comment: If you google "php double colon" your first result is: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It allows you to call a static function/method in a class, without making an instance of the class:

```
class myClass{

static function myFunction(){
echo"foo";
}
}
```

now call it like this with `::`

```
myClass::myFunction;
```

with a public function, you would have to make an instance:

```
$mycalssinstance= new myCalss;
//then call it
$mycalssfunction=$mycalssinstance->myFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's [Scope Resolution Operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) (also called Paamayim Nekudotayim). It allows you to access constants or static methods.

Answer (score 0):

Call to a static (class) method.  You can call this without an instance of the class.

http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php

Answer (score 0):

It is a reference to a static php function

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php